# How to identify the required custom action using ORCA tool & how to bring it before InstallValidate using ORCA?

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-installer, custom-action, orca

Hi am upgrading an application. My newer version of app should install over the older version.  But the older version runs a windows service. I want to stop this service by overriding the OnBeforeInstall() method of Installer class & including the stopService code in it.

Hi I have a VS2005 set up project. Have included primary output of the Installer class to the custom actions of set up project.

But I want to bring this "Custom actions" before "InstallValidate" using ORCA tool.

I don't know how to identify my custom action in "Custom actions" table or "InstallExecuteSequence" table.

PLz help me.

Thanks I Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- in your setup project note the custom action name
- open your MSI with Orca
- select InstallExecuteSequence table
- click the Action column to order the rows by name
- find your action
- modify its Sequence column value to be lower that InstallValidate sequence